# How to use cocoapods inside swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

im developing a framework and i added alamofire with cocoapods inside my frame work but when i add my frame work to my target app it crashes with this error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9426EAA-64AA-4A24-A50E-24CA9781ED02/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D068D428-93BA-4224-A673-4456C8A67B41/hovitaSignSdkTest.app/Frameworks/cryptography.framework/cryptography
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/20C69/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4.18D46
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hovitaSignSdkTest-fktcpojeagezfbacyzycszboqcfd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/Cor
```

and i did add **Embed&Sign** to my target app for my framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this issue by adding `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Alamofire` to **Build Settings>Runpath Search Paths**

[image]